# Can tin(IV) sulfide be synthesized from tin(II) chloride via oxidation with sulfite in acidic media?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution

Will the following reaction occur?

$$\ce{2Na2SO3 + 6SnCl2 + 12HCl → 4NaCl + 5SnCl4 + SnS2 + 6H2O}$$

I'm going to synthesizing $\ce{SnS}$ and $\ce{SnS2}$ NP's, but our supply is runned out and deadline of assignment is coming to soon, so will this reaction  occur? If it is possible, what is are the conditions of this reaction?

Comment: You are using a reducing agent, sulfite, to effect an oxidation.

Comment: @user55119 "reducing agent" is a relative term. Sulfite might act like one with strong oxidizers, but SnCl2 is even better reducing agent in comparison, making sulfite act as oxidant, although the oxidizing effect is even more pronounced among selenites and tellurites.

Comment: Do you not have hydrogen sulfide?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the reaction

$$\ce{2 Na2SO3 + 6 SnCl2 + 12 HCl → 4 NaCl + 5 SnCl4 + SnS2 + 6 H2O}$$

is described in chapter *35.6.4 Reactions of chalcogen oxo-compounds* of the Russian translation [1, p. 526] of Blumenthal's *Anorganikum* 10th Ed. (in German).
Unfortunately, I don't posses original German edition, so the following is my English translation of the procedure:

> To the 0.5 M solution of $\ce{SnCl2}$ in 12 M $\ce{HCl}$ in three test tubes 0.2 M solutions containing $\ce{SO3^2-}$, $\ce{SeO3^2-}$ and $\ce{TeO3^2-}$ are added. In all three tubes precipitations of $\ce{SnS2}$, $\ce{Se}$, and $\ce{Te}$, respectively, are formed.

Original Russian text:

> К 0.5 M раствору $\ce{SnCl2}$ в 12 M $\ce{HCl}$, находящемуся в трех пробирках, 
>   приливают 0.2 M растворы, содержащие $\ce{SO3^2-}$, $\ce{SeO3^2-}$ и $\ce{TeO3^2-}$. Во всех трех пробирках наблюдается выпадение осадков, которые представляют со­бой $\ce{SnS2}$, $\ce{Se}$ и $\ce{Te}$ соответственно.

#### References

1. G. Blumenthal, S. Engels, I. Fitz, W. Haberditzl, K.-H. Heckner, G. Henrion, R. Landsberg, W. Schmidt, G. Scholz, P. Starke, I. Wilke, K.-Th. Wilke Anorganikum: Lehr- und Praktikumsbuch der anorganischen Chemie mit einer Einführung in die physikalische Chemie; Ed. of Russian translation: L. Kolditz; *Mir: Moscow*, **1984**; Vol. 1.

Comment: Now that's something I didn't expect.

Comment: @IvanNeretin "*Anorganikum: Überraschend anders!*" :D